# Social Poster Setup Qeustion

Tags: plugins

When using a plugin such as Social Provider https://verbb.io/craft-plugins/social-poster/docs/providers/facebook and setting up LinkedIn/Twitter/Facebook do you have your clients login and follow the instructions so everything is under their account?

Or do you do it yourself?

Not sure what the best practice is here

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about best practice, but we always use our clients details. They normally own the site, so they should also own the social login flow.

We normally ask them to let us set it up, then they can change the password with the provider (if they want to) once it is working.

Comment: I think that is probably the best approach. Will talk to client about getting login creds for FB, LinkedIn, and Twitter